# EntityManager not returning fully populating objects of newly created entries

Tags: jsf, jpa, ejb, persistence, cdi

I've created an entity which maps to a database table.  Notice that it contains references to two foreign keys in two other tables and it stores those entries as Person and Escrow objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ESCROW_MANAGER")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "EscrowManager.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM EscrowManager e"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EscrowManager.findByUserId", query = "SELECT e FROM EscrowManager e WHERE e.escrowManagerPK.userId = :userId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EscrowManager.findByEscrowId", query = "SELECT e FROM EscrowManager e WHERE e.escrowManagerPK.escrowId = :escrowId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EscrowManager.findByActive", query = "SELECT e FROM EscrowManager e WHERE e.active = :active"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "EscrowManager.findByViewed", query = "SELECT e FROM EscrowManager e WHERE e.viewed = :viewed")})

public class EscrowManager implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected EscrowManagerPK escrowManagerPK;    

    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Person person;

    @JoinColumn(name = "ESCROW_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Escrow escrow;
```

When I start up the application and I query the EM for a list of EscrowManagers, it works great.

```
public List<EscrowManager> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

I get a full list of entries, every EscrowManager contains a Person and Escrow field which are populated with the right objects.  All is well.

I then create a new EscrowManager using em.persist().  This also, seems to work well.  I check the database and the new EscrowManager entry is there in the table.

But when I query the EM for the list of EscrowManager again...the new list contains all of the EscrowManagers and all of them are fully populated with Person and Escrow objects EXCEPT THE ONE I ADDED.  This happens to every new one I add.

Why wouldn't it be populated like the others?

If I restart the application server, all of the EscrowManager entries are fully populated again with the Person and Escrow fields.  This only happens with new entries.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: As requested in the comments:

The project is an web application, using EJBs and CDI Managed Beans, on an application server:

My facelets page calls the "create" method of the EJB:

```
@Named("escrowController")
@SessionScoped
public class EscrowController implements Serializable {

    private Escrow current;

    @EJB
    EscrowFacade ejbFacade;

    public String create() {  
        getFacade().create(managerName, current);
        return "create";
    }
    ...
```

And here is the EJB.  Notice that first is creates the Escrow, then it creates the EscrowManager using the ID from the newly created Escrow.

```
@Stateless
public class EscrowFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EscrowPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public EscrowFacade() {
    }

    public void create(String managerName, Escrow escrow) {

        //create escrow
        getEntityManager().persist(escrow);
        getEntityManager().flush();

        //create escrow manager
        EscrowManagerPK pk = new EscrowManagerPK(managerName, escrow.getId());
        EscrowManager escrowManager = new EscrowManager(pk, 1, 1);
        getEntityManager().persist(escrowManager);        
        getEntityManager().flush();
    }
    ...
```

And, in case this is helpful, here is our persistence declaration:

```
<persistence-unit name="EscrowPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/swrescrow</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I think you should post the method which calls `em.persist()` and creates the entities.

Comment: We need more information. Are you using an Application Server or Client environment. Do you have transactions, are they managed?

Comment: I put the answers to your questions in the post.